# Replace text inside textarea with js. Why only works first time?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the text inside a textarea when a button is pressed.

For some reason this only works the first time the button is clicked. How to fix this?

```
<button id = "the_button">replace text</button> <br>

<textarea id = "textarea"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
 $("#the_button").click(function(e) {
       $("#textarea").html("hello world");
});
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FU4gL/

Comment: Well, what do you expect after clicking 2nd time? You changed text to "hello world" and then you want to change it again to "hello world" so  nothing will happend, won't it?

Comment: Check the jsfiddle: click it, change the text manually, and then click it again. It does not change to "hello world" the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#the_button").click(function(e) {
    $("#textarea").html("hello world");
});
```

to:

```
$("#the_button").click(function(e) {
    $("#textarea").val("hello world");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$("#the_button").click(function(e) {
  $("#textarea").val("hello world");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrikesh/HEPwj/